# JComboBox loses focus after typing one character

Tags: java, swing, awt, jcombobox

I extended JComboBox to add the autocomplete feature. This is the code:

```
public class AutocompleteJComboBox extends JComboBox{

static final long serialVersionUID = 4321421L;

private final Searchable<String,String> searchable;

/**
 * Constructs a new object based upon the parameter searchable
 * @param s
 */

public AutocompleteJComboBox(Searchable<String,String> s){

    super();
    this.searchable = s;
    setEditable(true);
    Component c = getEditor().getEditorComponent();

    if (c instanceof JTextComponent){
        final JTextComponent tc = (JTextComponent)c;
        tc.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener(){

            @Override
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent arg0) {}

            @Override
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent arg0) {
                update();
            }

            @Override
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent arg0) {
                update();
            }

            public void update(){
                //perform separately, as listener conflicts between the editing component
                //and JComboBox will result in an IllegalStateException due to editing 
                //the component when it is locked. 
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        List<String> founds = new ArrayList<String>(searchable.search(tc.getText()));
                        Set<String> foundSet = new HashSet<String>();
                        for ( String s : founds ){
                            foundSet.add(s.toLowerCase());
                        }
                        Collections.sort(founds);//sort alphabetically

                        setEditable(false);
                        removeAllItems();
                        //if founds contains the search text, then only add once.
                        if ( !foundSet.contains( tc.getText().toLowerCase()) ){
                            addItem( tc.getText() );
                        }

                        for (String s : founds) {
                            addItem(s);
                        }

                        setEditable(true);
                        setPopupVisible(true);
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        //When the text component changes, focus is gained 
        //and the menu disappears. To account for this, whenever the focus
        //is gained by the JTextComponent and it has searchable values, we show the popup.

        tc.addFocusListener(new FocusListener(){
            @Override
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent arg0) {
                System.out.println("Focus gained");
                if ( tc.getText().length() > 0 ){
                    setPopupVisible(true);
                }
                tc.requestFocusInWindow();
            }

            @Override
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent arg0) {    
                System.out.println("Focus lost");

            }
        });
    }else{
        throw new IllegalStateException("Editing component is not a JTextComponent!");
    }
}
```

}

Now, the autocomplete part work just fine. The problem is that after I type one character, it loses focus (focus goes to my other UI element, a plain JTextField). I have to mention that if the UI contains only this combo box, it works perfectly, no focus lost (because there are no other elements, I assume).

Any idea what I might be doing wrong here? Thanks.

Comment: What happens when you change the empty method to this? `@Override
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent arg0) { update() ;}`

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: @Juvanis nothing changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is not too late, and for everybody struggling with this, I added `requestFocus()` at the end of the `update()` method. It is kind of a workaround but seems to work fine.
Another addition to this implementation of auto complete combobox is to add

```
putClientProperty("JComboBox.isTableCellEditor", Boolean.TRUE);
```

in the constructor which enables you to cycle trough popup items using up nad down arrow keys without changing the input in combobox.